# ldd exits with error on armhf target

Tags: dynamic, floating-point, arm, libraries, abi

I have been facing the following issue on an armhf ubuntu target (arm9, omap4). I am trying to execute the maliit keyboard using Ubuntu 12.04 arm-linux-gnueabihf toolchain. I successfully cross compiled Qt5 and the different libs used by maliit-framework but when executing maliit-server or maliit-exampleapp-plainqt it exits right after the dynamic libraries have been opened. Here is the end of strace output :

```
open("/mnt/internal/library/icu_4.8.1.1/lib/libicudata.so.48", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0T\2\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 18280604, SEEK_SET)            = 18280604
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 480) = 480
lseek(3, 18280460, SEEK_SET)            = 18280460
read(3, "A \0\0\0aeabi\0\1\26\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4,"..., 33) = 33
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I first thought it was related to an arm floating point incompatibility between the different libraries but a readelf -h on the libraries gives me this (except for some of them that have       Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed) :

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

I can see through strace that all the libraries have been found. Grepping "aeabi" on strace gives me the following output :

```
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\3\f"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A4\0\0\0aeabi\0\1*\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 53) = 53
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A6\0\0\0aeabi\0\1,\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 55) = 55
read(3, "A \0\0\0aeabi\0\1\26\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4,"..., 33) = 33
```

ldd also exits without displaying all the different libraries needed and returns 1.

Does anyone know what is here happening ?

Comment: Link is working without using the libuci I manually cross compiled ... using the one provided by Ubuntu let the linker do his job till the end. Kind of weird since the readlink -Ah outputs of the uci libs were the same as other libs.

Comment: Try adding `LD_DEBUG=all` to your environment before running.